# SUT - Testing Internal Behaviour TDD

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, tdd, bdd

I have a question about testing requirements.

Let's take example:

```
Class Article {

    public void deactive() {//some behaviour, which deactives article}

}
```

I have in my requirements, that Article can be `deactived`. I will implement it as part of my `Article` class.

Test will call `deactive` method, but what now? I need to check at the end of the test, if requirement was fulfilled so I need to implement method `isDeactived`.
And here is my question, if I really should do it? This method will be only used by my test case, nowhere else. So I am complicating my class interface, just to see assert, if is really deactived.

What is the right way to implement it?

Comment: What happens if you call deactivate on an already deactivated Article?  How does *something* know that the Article can/should be dactivated?

Answer (score 1):

It's generally considered ok to add test hooks to a class. It's better to have a slightly more cluttered interface and know your class works than it is to make it untestable. But there are some other solutions.

If you're ok making your method protected or package-private, you might be able to use something like [Guava's @VisibleForTesting annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913325/annotation-to-make-a-private-method-public-only-for-test-classes). Languages other than Java might have other similar libraries.

You could also inherit from Article to get access to private fields.

```
class ArticleTest extends Article {
    @Test
    public void deactiveTest() {
        this.deactive();
        assertTrue(this.isDeactive);    
    }
}
```

This all assumes you have some field you're using to mark whether the object is active or not.

It might be the case that you're causing some side effects, like calling the database, and a couple of services to say you're deactivating that article. If so, you should mock the collaborators that you're using to make the side effects and verifying that you're calling them correctly.

For example (in java/mockito like pseudocode):

```
@Test
public void deactiveTest() {
    Article underTest = new Article(databaseMock, httpMock); //or use dependency injection framework of your choice...
    underTest.deactive();
    verify(databaseMock).calledOnce().withParams(expectedParams);
    verify(httpMock).calledOnce().withParams(expectedParams);
}
```

A final possibility, if that field affects the behavior of some other method or function, you could try (again in pseudocode):

```
article.deactive()
result = article.post() // maybe returns true if active, else false?
assertFalse(result)
```

This way, you're testing the resulting behavior, not just checking the internal state.

Comment: Well I am using PHP. And there isn't something like protected scope in Java. Neither a library which allows that. I would have to go for Reflection class and making the private property public. But my tests will become more messy. But I guess it's the cost to pay, right?

Comment: PHP has inheritance, at least one DI framework (although you don't need one if you're using constructor parameters) and the ability to create mocks via php-unit. That's all you need.

Comment: I am not talking about mocking here. I am talking about System Under Test (SUT). The class, which is tested here do not use any collaborators. 
The problem here is about creating public method to show internal state of the SUT, just for test purpose.

Comment: Well I guess Reflection Class is not going to solve the problem. It will couple my test case with my class. If I change name of the property in my class for example and I will need to change my test case.

Comment: It sounds like none of the approaches are ideal, but that points to deficiencies in the language you're using. I'd suggest when choosing between them to consider what solution is the most readable to your future self, and if you do end up coupling to the implementation, that it will be something unlikely or easy to change, such as the name of a field. e.g. your development environment should be able to change the name of a field wherever it's used.

Comment: Well you may be right ;). I am looking for perfect solution and may be there is none. Well anyway I will keep this topic open for a while, maybe someone will come with something interesting.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are writing a test along the lines of:

```
assertThatCallingDeactiveMarksArticleAsDeactivated
```

With an `isDeactivated` method, this test becomes trivial, however as you've said, your `Article` class doesn't contain this method.  So, the question becomes *should* it have that method.  The answer really depends on what it really means for the `Article` class to be `deactive`.

I would expect and `active Article` to behave differently in some way from a `deactive Article`.  Otherwise, it seems like the state change doesn't have a reason / there is nothing to test.

To give a practical example, looking at it from the perspective of a client of the `Article` class. *Something* triggers the call to `deactive`.  It may be something as simple as the user clicking on a Deactivate button/link on the user interface, which calls through to the `Article` class.  After this call, I'd expect the user interface to reflect in some way that the `Article` was deactive (for example by greying out the button/link), but for it to do that, the UI needs to be able to read the state of the `Article`, which brings us back to the question how does it do that and/or why isn't the `isDeactivated` method needed by the current code?

Without knowing more about the implementation of the `deactive` method (does it simply set a flag, or does it call out to other code in an observable way) and how the state change effects the behaviour of `Article` and it clients it's hard to give a more concrete response.

Comment: It does simply set a flag. It doesn't call any other object, neither any other other call isActive or isDeactived on Article. User calls deactive just like you said. But how does he read the value without public get method? By using CQRS and separating write/read. Article is write model, it's loaded only for write operations, never for read ones. And Read model goes directly to the database using clear SQLs.

Comment: @Dariss If the Article is being written to the database then I would expect that you are calling the database (in which case there should be scope for mocking/stubbing), or the database framework is accessing the fields of your  class in which case you should be able to use the same approach to access them from your tests.  That said, some people advocate that you don't need to test simple setter functionality http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197370/should-unit-tests-be-written-for-getter-and-setters and if it's unlikely to change often, a simple integration test may be the way to go...

Comment: My db framework is ORM and he doesn't use set/get method, but reflection. But your integration test advice is helpful. But instead of integration I would write there functional. :)

Comment: @Dariss If you do want to write a unit test and your ORM uses reflection to access your class fields without you needing to expose them, then it seems like testing your method by using reflection would be the way to go.  The bit that you care about is 'Does calling deactive set the field used by your ORM', not 'Does calling isDeactived return true after you have called deactive'.  Adding an extra method in this case, just seems like it would just add scope for you to be testing the wrong thing...

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you don't want to test the internals of a method or class, as this makes tests brittle and tightly coupled. If you refactor the production code, your test has a higher change of also needing to be refactored, thus going the benefit of the test. You want to try and test the classes behaviour as a whole (i.e what does calling deactivate do)

Check out Kent Beck's 4 rules for simple design (in priority order).

1) All Tests Pass

2) Expresses Intent

3) Eliminates Duplication

4) Fewest Elements

The last rule is that a system shouldn't be any larger than it needs to be, which is where your question falls. Given this is the *least* important element and that its better to 1) pass a test and 2) express intent, it would be acceptable (in my view) to simply add an isActive() method.

This also makes the class more useful and generic, as is you deactivate something, it seems logical to be able to verify its state.

Also as previously mentioned, there must be an effect of calling deactivate which in itself should be tested, so try and test this - It maybe an Integration Test is better placed, or you have to mock or stub another class.