# Why should I use an interface when there is only one implementation class?

Tags: java, interface, implementation

I'm new at programming and I'm learning Java. 
I was just wondering why I should use an interface when there is only one implementation class?

Comment: Reopened because this question is significantly more specific than the alleged duplicate.

Comment: For the record, if anyone is interested in what the "alleged duplicate" was, like myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321122/what-is-an-interface-in-java

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You do this to prevent others from accessing your implementing type. For example, you could hide your implementing type inside a library, give the type package access, and return an instance of your interface to the users of your library:

```
// This is what the users of your library know about the class
// that does the work:
public interface SomeInterface {
    void doSomethingUseful();
    void doSomethingElse();
}

// This is the class itself, which is hidden from your clients
class MyImplementation implements SomeInterface {
    private SomeDependency dependency = new SomeDependency();
    public void doSomethingUseful() {
        ...
    }
    public void doSomethingElse() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Your clients obtain objects like this:

```
public class MyFactory {
    static SomeInterface make() {
        // MyFactory can see MyImplementation
        return new MyImplementation();
    }
}
```

This trick becomes useful when the implementation uses lots of libraries. You efficiently decouple the interface of your library from its implementation, so that the user wouldn't have to know about the dependencies internal to your library.

Comment: I don't see the difference between handing the user an Interface vs. handing the user the implementation Class. The "look and feel" is the same ...

Comment: @Nitek: here's an example solved by this, where the OP wants to expose public methods to tests that he doesn't want to expose to the end-user: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6913509/217324

Comment: @Nitek That's not about look and feel, it's about isolating users of your library from things they are not supposed to see.

Comment: Not sure it's good style to make methods public for tests and then try to hide them. I get that there might be a few cases where this might make sense, but I'd consider this more like an edge case then good programming style.

Comment: Maybe worth saying that there are also many situations where YAGNI is a good default...

Answer (score 6):

You shoulnt do anything without thinking and reasoning.

There might be cases where you might want to add an interface even for a single implementation ... but IMO that's an **OBSOLETE PRACTICE** coming from old EJB times, that people use and enforce without the proper reasoning and reflection.

... and both Martin Fowler, Adan Bien, and others has been saying it for years.

https://martinfowler.com/bliki/InterfaceImplementationPair.html

https://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/service_s_new_serviceimpl_why

Comment: There are so many times when YAGNI applies here. You Ain't Gonna Need It!!!

Answer (score 3):

One reason is to maintain the open/closed principle, which states that your code should be open for extension, but closed for modification. Although you only have one implementing class now, chance is that you will need another differing implementation class with the passing of time. If you extract the implementation into an interface beforehand, you just have to write another implementing class ie. You don't have to modify a perfectly working piece of code, eliminating the risks of introducing bugs.

Answer (score 2):

To respect the Interface Segregation Principle.

The decision to create an interface should not be based on the number of implementing classes, but rather on the number of different ways that object is used. Each ways the object is used is represented by an interface, defined with the code that uses it. Say your object needs to be stored in memory, in collections that keep objects in order. That same object and also needs to be stored in some persistent storage.

Say you implement persistence first. What is needed by the storage system is a unique identifier for the persisted objects. You create an interface, say Storable, with a method getUniqueId. You then implement the storage.

Then, you implement the collection. You define what the collection needs from stored objects in an interface, like Comparable, with a method compareTo. You can then implement the collection with dependency on Comparable.

The class you want to define would implement both interfaces.

If the class you are defining implement a single interface, that interface would have to represent the needs of the collection and storage system. That would cause, for example:

- unit tests for the collection would have to be written with objects that implement Storable, adding a level of complexity.
- if the need arise later to display the object, you would have to add methods needed by the display code to the single interface, and modify the tests for collection and storage to also implement the methods needed for display.

I talk about impact on test code here. The problem is larger if other production level objects need storage and not display. The larger the project, the larger the issue created by not respecting the interface segregation principle will become.

Answer (score 0):

It can give you the flexibility to add more implementations in the future without changing the client code which references the interface.

Another example of when it can be useful is to simulate multiple inheritance in Java when it is needed. For example, suppose you have an interface `MyInterface` and an implementation:

```
public interface MyInterface {
  void aMethod1();
  void aMethod2();
}

class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {
  public void aMethod1() {...}
  public void aMethod2() {...}
}
```

You also have an unrelated class with its own hierarchy:

```
public class SomeClass extends SomeOtherClass {
 ...
}
```

Now you want to make `SomeClass` be of type `MyInterface` but you also want to inherit all the code that is already existing in `MyInterfaceImpl`. Since you cannot extend both `SomeOtherClass` and `MyInterfaceImpl`, you can implement the interface and use delegation:

```
public class SomeClass extends SomeOtherClass implements MyInterface {
  private MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterfaceImpl();

  public void aMethod1() {
    myInterface.aMethod1();
  }

  public void aMethod2() {
    myInterface.aMethod2();
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of good points being made in this post. Also wanted to add my 2 cents to this collection of knowledge.

Interfaces Encourage parallel development in a team environment. There can be 2 classes A and B, with A calling B's API. There can be 2 developers simultaneously working on A and B. while B is not ready, A can totally go about it's own implementation by integrating with B's interfaces.

Interfaces serve as a good ground for establishing API Contracts between different layers of code.

It's good to have a separation of concerns with Interface handling implicit API documentation. it's super easy to refer to one and figure which APIs are accessible for the clients to call.

Lastly, it's better to practice using interfaces as a standard in a project than having to use it on a case by case bases (where you need multiple implementations). This ensures consistency in your project.

For the Art that Java Code is, interfaces make thmem even more beautiful :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many good answers to this question. And my contribution is:

The interface allows you to perform code substitution without having to make changes to the code that is currently using it.

This is particularly useful for unit testing, since it allows to replace the code that is actually executed by one prepared with a particular feature/situation/configuration/calculation such as simulating* access to a database, a file, a Web Service, a mail and even prepared to test the error cases thus verifying that the code is well executed and also correctly handles the error cases and special cases. This feature of the interface can even be used for development, refactoring and testing without affecting de current code.

So if you don't have that interface you won't be able to do the substitution and therefore the automatic unit tests would not be able to take advantage of the benefits mentioned above.

If you want to see a more visual example of this I recommend you to watch the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1f5b4vcxCQ&list=PLotziLf0XP1htK1RYUd1GR13ly7suM-IC&index=2&t=667s

*In java the act of substitute to simulation or test is called "mock"

Happy Coding;

Answer (score -5):

Interfaces can be implemented by multiple classes. There is no rule that only one class can implement these. Interfaces provide abstraction to the java.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm
You can get more information about interfaces from this link

Comment: This is a "link-only answer", which is considered bad form on StackOverflow because links go bad. Ask yourself how good the answer would be without the link. Unless you're prepared to make the answer sufficiently self-contained, it should be a comment instead.

Comment: I don't think the asker thinks you are limited in one implementation class. I think they were more wondering why someone would split out the interface in the case where they only had one implementation class.