# Anything similar to @VisibleForTesting annotation to use in Typescript or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, typescript, testing

There's a `@VisibleForTesting` annotation available in Java through the Google Guava library to indicate that the visibility of a type or member has been relaxed to make the code testable: [annotation to make a private method public only for test classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913325/annotation-to-make-a-private-method-public-only-for-test-classes) . Subsequently there are also plugins which ensure that the methods which are annotated with `@VisibleForTesting` are actually being used only in the test classes.

I currently have a typescript interface where I have to add some methods to the interface just for testing purposes. For example:

```js
interface ProcessorInterface {
  process(data: Readonly<Data>): Promise<Result>;

  // these 2 methods are only added here so that they are 
  // callable from the implementation while writing tests.
  processBatch(data: Readonly<Data>): Promise<Result>;
  validate(data: Readonly<Data>): Promise<Error[]>;
}
```

I was wondering if there is a *standard* way in Typescript to indicate the same.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: If you are testing a concrete implementation of the interface, there are several options including extracting the functions you want to test and importing them into the interface's implementations as private methods. This StackOverflow includes those options including array access and using the type-ignore flag in your tests. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56199483/1078187